# How to find out if the distributions are the same?

Tags: r

I measured the isoelectric points of proteins in two samples (A and B). These proteins can be divided into two groups (G1 and G2). A fictional example for the G1 group is given below:

```
G1  pH-2   pH-4   pH-6   pH-8
A   10     2      5      2
B   15     4      9      1
```

So, sample A has 10 proteins with isoelectric point of pH 2 and 2 of pH 4 and so on. For the G2 group the values are the following:

```
G2  pH-2   pH-4   pH-6   pH-8
A   13     6      2      1
B   22     12     30     1
```

As can be seen, both samples have similar values in the G1 group, but they are not similar in the G2 group. I'm not a statistician, so I'd like to ask how could use R to compare the distributions/values for A and B inside G1 group and for A and B inside G2 group. Anybody could help me?

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd plot the distribution by group. You are going to need to fix the format of your data so that it looks like:

```
Group pH Count
 A     2  13
 A     4   6
 ... ...  ...
 A     8   1
 B     2  22
 .. ...  ...
 B     8   1
```

and then plot

```
# using ggplot2
ggplot(data, aes(x = pH, y = Count, color = Group)) + 
  geom_point()
```

and see if they look different.

As far as testing, you'd probably want to use a chi squared test or Fisher's exact test (if you have small counts). Use something like below:

```
x <- as.table(rbind(c(13, 6, 2, 1), c(22, 12, 30, 1)))
dimnames(x) <- list(G2 = c("A","A"),
                    ph = c("2", "4", "6", "8"))
chisq.test(x)
fisher.test(x)
```

Comment: Thank you iacobus, I will try what you suggested. Can these tests be used with different sample sizes? I have more measured values for one sample than the other.

Comment: Yes, the chi square test or Fisher's test should still work. One thing to note about the chi square test is that if any cell has an expected count <= 5 OR has a zero, it might not be suitable. R will warn you in this case. Fisher's exact test should be fine regardless.